# Meteor getting this.params._id undefined

Tags: meteor, iron-router

UPDATE: I got the issue fixed, it was due to my Meteor Publish setting I had to change it to return Links.find(); and then filter the correct data in my links list return Links.find({topicId: this._id}, {sort:{submitted: -1}});

So I'm getting some very weird issue and I'm really stuck.

I have the following route setup

```
this.route('linkEdit', {
        path: '/link/:_id/edit',
        data: function() {
           console.log(this.params);
           console.log(this.params._id);
           console.log(Links.findOne(this.params._id));
           return Links.findOne(this.params._id)
         }
    });
```

So this.params is fine I'm getting - `[_id: "LiAiifzPHmMR23tg3", hash: undefined]`
For `this.params._id` - I'm getting the correct ID, LiAiifzPHmMR23tg3
But for `Links.findOne(this.params._id)` - I'm getting undefined

However when I check mongodb I have a link with that ID.

Also if I add an alert, while the alert is popping up the template renders the data but then re-renders and I'm getting blank data as it can't find the correct link ID.

Answer (score -1):

That's because your collection query is a bit off, you'll want to change that to the following:

```
Links.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that's not the issue just got it working main issue was my publish setting.

Comment: Like Almog said, `<Collection>.findOne(<documentId>)` is equivalent to `<Collection>.findOne({_id: <documentId>})`. http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors